# how to pass invisible information in a POST form, using django?

Tags: html, django, forms

I am trying to create a chat website, but when I want to send a message I must use a tool to pass within the form of the message an invisible information that will contains the other user username to be able to send the message to him.

I would like some suggestions such as a hidden input field or something like that.

NOTE: I am using django 3.0.8 for backend! Help pls

Comment: Hey guys I would like some suggestions such as a hidden input field or something like that, I hope you understood that!

Comment: I incorporated your comment into the question. Please, make sure that the question contains all the info. For example, it could be grate if you could post the code of your attempt. Without it it is impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  "*hidden*" as the input type. and also don't forget to give it a "*name*" attribute as well.

Example:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="customerId" name="customerId" value="3487">
```

Comment: Thank you, but why is the name attribute so necessary?

Comment: Since you are submitting the form to a view.  the "name" attribute is used as reference form data after a form is submitted.

Comment: oh yeah thank you, but actually how can we access an input field content in our view, is it with ```form.cleaned_data["the_name_here"]```?

Comment: Is the "form" mentioned a ModelForm or are you using request.POST?
it should be available in request.POST.get("customerId")

Comment: I am using a request.POST passed into the form class that inherits from forms.Form

Comment: Then yeah you should be able to get the hidden field by using form.cleaned_data.get("customerId"). Please note- the "custormerId" mentioned is from the name attribute.

Comment: If I have answered your query, please upvote the answer.

Comment: I cannot upvote now cause I don't have 15 reputation yet but I selected your answer as the best one so now u have 16 reputations so upvote my answer pls if u can

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys I think I found the solution, in fact I've already said it in the comment it is simply a hidden input with the default value so that the user cannot change its value!